# Magento email Outlook.com

Tags: email, email-templates

We use the Magento 1.9.1 email template for sending emails to customers.
Everything works great, except for Outlook.com.

Outlook.com does not support margin-left: auto; and margin-right: auto;.
So how can we fix the problem that the email is aligned left, not in the center?

We use this code:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

<table  class="table-bestelling-content" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#ffffff">
    <tr align="center" class="header" style="max-width: 600px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <td align="center">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%;" >
                <tr>
                    <td class="email-heading head">
                        <h1>ORDERBEVESTIGING</h1>
                        <p>Hi {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerFirstname()}},</p> 
                        <p>Bedankt voor je bestelling!</p>
                        <p>Je bestelling heeft ordernummer {{var order.increment_id}}.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="details">
        <td class="order-details">
            <h1>OVERZICHT BESTELLING</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="order-information">
        <td>
            {{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/if}}
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr class="address-block">
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h6>FACTUURADRES</h6>
                        <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h6>AFLEVERADRES</h6>
                        <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h6>BETAALWIJZE</h6>
                        {{var payment_html}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

Header:

```
<!--@subject Email - Header @-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
{{var non_inline_styles}}
<!-- Begin wrapper table -->
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="background-table">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="container-td" align="center">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="container-table">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="table-bestelling-header" cellpadding="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="logo-container" style="background-color:#f0575c;">
                            <tr style="max-width: 600px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                                <td class="logo">
                                    <a href="{{store url=""}}">
                                        <img
                                            {{if logo_width}}
                                            width="{{var logo_width}}"
                                            {{else}}
                                            width="165"
                                            {{/if}}

                                            {{if logo_height}}
                                            height="{{var logo_height}}"
                                            {{else}}
                                            height="50"
                                            {{/if}}

                                            src="{{var logo_url}}"
                                            alt="{{var logo_alt}}"
                                            border="0"/>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" class="content-data top-content">
                    <!-- Begin Content -->
```

Footer:

```
<!--@subject Email - Footer @-->
                    <!-- End Content -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="footer-blocks">
                <td style="background-color:#f2f2f2; border-radius:5px;">

                    <table class="footer-blocks-side" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr class="footer-blocks-topper">
                            <td class="footer-blocks-top">
                                <table class="footer-blocks-left" width="225" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        <h4 class="footer-blocks-title">SUGGESTIES?</h4>
                                        <p>Text</p>
                                        <p>Text</p>
                                        <a class="underline" style="color: #333333;" href="/test">
                                        Mail je suggesties door</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table class="footer-blocks-center" width="225" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        <h4 class="footer-blocks-title">SERVICE</h4>
                                        <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                        <img class="icon-vinkje" style="width:22px; height:22px; vertical-align:middle" src=/test">
                                        <p class="tekst-vinkje" style="padding-left: 5px; display: inline-block;">Gratis verzending</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                        <img class="icon-vinkje" style="width:22px; height:22px; vertical-align:middle" src="/test">
                                        <p class="tekst-vinkje" style="padding-left: 5px; display: inline-block;">14 dagen bedenktermijn</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                        <img class="icon-vinkje" style="width:22px; height:22px; vertical-align:middle" src="/test">
                                        <p class="tekst-vinkje" style="padding-left: 5px; display: inline-block;">Statusupdates via e-mail</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                        <img class="icon-vinkje" style="width:22px; height:22px; vertical-align:middle" src="/test">
                                        <p class="tekst-vinkje" style="padding-left: 5px; display: inline-block;">Deskundig hulp en advies</p>
                                        </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table class="footer-blocks-right" width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        <img src="/test">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table class="footer-blocks-side" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr class="footer-blocks-bottom">
                            <td class="footer-blocks-bottom">
                                <table class="footer-blocks-left contact" width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="icon">
                                        <a href="/test">
                                        <img style="height: 30px;" src="/test">
                                        </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="contact">
                                        <a class="non-link" href="/test">
                                        <h4 class="footer-blocks-title contact">BELLEN</h4>
                                        <p class="footer-blocks-contact"></p>
                                        </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table class="footer-blocks-center contact" width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="icon">
                                        <a href="/test">
                                        <img style="height: 30px;" src="/test">
                                        </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="contact">
                                        <a class="non-link" href="/test">
                                        <h4 class="footer-blocks-title contact">MAILEN</h4>
                                        <p class="footer-blocks-contact">Antwoord in 2 uur</p>
                                        </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table class="footer-blocks-left contact" width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="icon">
                                        <a href="/test">
                                        <img style="height: 30px;" src="/test">
                                        </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="contact">
                                        <a class="non-link" href="/test">
                                        <h4 class="footer-blocks-title contact">FACEBOOK</h4>
                                        <p class="footer-blocks-contact">Antwoord in 30 min.</p>
                                        </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table class="footer-blocks-right contact" width="150" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="icon">
                                        <a href="/test">
                                        <img style="height: 30px;" src="/test">
                                        </a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="contact">
                                        <a class="non-link" href="/test">
                                        <h4 class="footer-blocks-title contact">Twitter</h4>
                                        <p class="footer-blocks-contact">Antwoord in 30 min.</p>
                                        </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>


                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    </tr>

                    <tr class="footer-block-payment">
                <td style="background-color:#ffffff; border-radius:5px;">

                    <table class="footer-blocks-side" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr class="footer-blocks-bottomfoot">
                            <td class="footer-blocks-bottom">
                                <table class="footer-blocks-left icon" width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" align="left">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="payment-icon" style="display: none;">
                                        <img src="/test">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="payment-icon">
                                        <img src="/test">
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="payment-icon">
                                        <img src="/test">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                                <table class="footer-blocks-right icon" width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" align="right">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="contact">
                                        <a class="footer-blocks-link" href="/test">Algemene voorwaarden</a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="contact">
                                        <a class="footer-blocks-link" href="/test">Privacy</a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="contact">
                                        <a class="footer-blocks-link" href="/test">Contact</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>

                </tr>
               </tbody>
               </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tr>            
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End wrapper table -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the existing table in another 100% width `<table>` with `align="center"` and then make your existing `<table>` `max-width: 600px` instead of the `<tr>`.

```
<table  class="table-bestelling-content" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#ffffff">
    <tr align="center">
        <td align="center">
            <table  class="table-bestelling-content" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:#ffffff; max-width: 600px; display: block;">
                <tr align="center" class="header">
                    <td align="center">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%;" >
                            <tr>
                                <td class="email-heading head">
                                    <h1>ORDERBEVESTIGING</h1>
                                    <p>Hi {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerFirstname()}},</p> 
                                    <p>Bedankt voor je bestelling!</p>
                                    <p>Je bestelling heeft ordernummer {{var order.increment_id}}.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="details">
                    <td class="order-details">
                        <h1>OVERZICHT BESTELLING</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="order-information">
                    <td>
                        {{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        {{/if}}
                        {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr class="address-block">
                                <td class="address-details">
                                    <h6>FACTUURADRES</h6>
                                    <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                                </td>
                                {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                                <td class="address-details">
                                    <h6>AFLEVERADRES</h6>
                                    <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                                </td>
                                {{/depend}}
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="method-info">
                                    <h6>BETAALWIJZE</h6>
                                    {{var payment_html}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

This also might be better in a more generalized Stackexchange post, as it's not really specific to Magento, but is just an HTML email question.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, it works for this part, but I can't get it fixed with the footer and header. How do I need the fix these? I edit my question with footer and header.

Comment: Check the final HTML that you end up with in the email that gets sent out. Most likely the block that is included in your first template (`{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}`) needs to be moved into the wrapper table.

Comment: Thats what I tried, but that did not work. I also tried to add your lines to the header and footer template, but that also did not work.